Closed form for $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(e^x)-\cos(e^{-x})}{e^x-e^{-x}}dx$?
Is there a closed form for the following integral?
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(e^x)-\cos(e^{-x})}{e^x-e^{-x}}dx$$
I was actually simplifying the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\sinh(x))\sin(\cosh(x))}{\sinh(x)}dx$$
by utilizing trig-identities and hyperbolic identities. However, I didn't know where to go next after putting it in cosine-expoential form. The integral table had a formula of this and stated that this integral equals $\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(1)$, but WolframAlpha had a different numerical answer.

If you have been taught complex analysis, it might be worth rewriting the cosine part of the integral using complex exponentials and then doing contour integration. Otherwise, the way I am trying right now, is to substitute $u  = e^x$

$\frac{\cos\left(\mathrm{e}^{\pi}\right) \ln\left(\left|\mathrm{e}^{-x} - 1\right|\right) - \cos\left(\mathrm{e}^{\pi}\right) \ln\left(\mathrm{e}^{-x} + 1\right) + \sin\left(1\right) \operatorname{Si}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-x} + 1\right) + \cos\left(1\right) \operatorname{Ci}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-x} + 1\right) + \sin\left(1\right) \operatorname{Si}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-x} - 1\right) - \cos\left(1\right) \operatorname{Ci}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-x} - 1\right)}{2} + C$.                          That is your answer.

Substitution $u=\exp(-x)$ is better.

The answer to the above integral is $-\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(1)$. The reason WolframAlpha gives a different numerical answer is that the integrand is highly oscillatory so the convergence is a bit dodgy- if one increases the precision as seen here, Mathematica does numerically evaluate it correctly (and can give it explicitly as $-\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(1)$). This is a simple exercise in contour integration.

@KStar I wish I had mathematica ;_;
Thank you so much!!

Register for Wolfram Cloud. It is free and you access all Mathematica

@ClaudeLeibovici Mathematica in Wolfram Cloud isn't free ;_;
If you input any difficult math problems, it'll just say "This computation has exceeded the time limit for your plan."

I do not agree ! I used and still use it at home

Integrate as follows to avoid complex analysis
\begin{align} 
 &\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos e^{x}-\cos e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}} dx \\
=& \ \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos e^{x}-\cos1}{e^{x}-e^{-x}} \overset{t=e^x}{dx}+ \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos 1-\cos e^{-x}}{e^{x}-e^{-x}} \overset{t=e^{-x}}{dx}\\
=& \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos t-\cos 1}{t^{2}-1} dt
= \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos t-\cos 1}{t^{2}-1} dt\\
=& -\frac{\sin1}4 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (t+1)}{t+1} + \frac{\sin (t-1)}{t-1}\ dt\\
& + \frac{\cos1}4 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos (t+1)}{t+1} -\frac{1-\cos (t-1)}{t-1}\ dt\\
= & -\frac{\sin1}4(\pi+\pi)+ \frac{\cos1}4\cdot J= -\frac\pi2\sin1
\end{align}
where, with $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos (t+s)}{(t+s)^2} dt\overset{ibp}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (t+s)}{t+s}dt$
\begin{align} 
 J=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos (t+1)}{t+1} -\frac{1-\cos (t-1)}{t-1}\ dt
 =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos (t+s)}{t+s}\bigg|_{s=-1}^{s=1}\ dt\\
 =& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\sin (t+s)}{t+s}-\frac{1-\cos (t+s)}{(t+s)^2} \ ds\ {dt} =0
\end{align}

We can also show that the integral is equal to $$\operatorname{PV} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t)}{t^{2}-1} \, \mathrm dt.$$
As Rezerd Prime showed, $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(e^{x})-\cos(e^{-x})}{e^{x}-e^{-x}} \, \mathrm dx= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t)-\cos(\tfrac{1}{t})}{t^{2}-1} \, \mathrm dt.  $$
Then we have $$ \begin{align} \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t)-\cos(\tfrac{1}{t})}{t^{2}-1} \, \mathrm dt&= \frac{1}{2} \, \operatorname{PV} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t)-\cos(\tfrac{1}{t})}{t^{2}-1} \, \mathrm dt \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \left( \operatorname{PV} \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{\cos(t)}{t^{2}-1} \, \mathrm dt - \operatorname{PV} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\tfrac{1}{t})}{t^{2}-1} \, \mathrm dt\right) \\ &= \frac{1}{2}\left( \operatorname{PV} \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{\cos(t)}{t^{2}-1} \, \mathrm dt + \operatorname{PV} \int_{\infty}^{0}\frac{\cos(u)}{\tfrac{1}{u^{2}}-1} \,  \frac{\mathrm du}{u^{2}}\right)  \\ &= \operatorname{PV} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t)}{t^{2}-1} \, \mathrm dt \\ &=  \frac{1}{2} \, \operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(t)}{t^{2}-1} \, \mathrm dt \\ &=  \frac{1}{2} \, \Re \, \operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{it}}{t^{2}-1} \, \mathrm dt \\ &\overset{\clubsuit}{=} \frac{1}{2} \,  \Re\left(i \pi \operatorname*{Res}_{z=1} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^{2}-1}  + i \pi \operatorname*{Res}_{z=-1} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^{2}-1}\right) \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \left(i \pi \, \frac{e^{i}}{2} - i \pi \, \frac{e^{-i}}{2}\right) \\ &= - \frac{\pi \sin(1)}{2}. \end{align}$$

$\clubsuit$ Integrate around a contour consisting of the real axis from $-R$ to $R$, with small clockwise-oriented semicircles about $z= \pm 1$, and the upper half of the circle $|z|=R$.

Notice what integrand is even:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(e^x)-\cos(e^{-x})}{e^x-e^{-x}}dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(e^x)-\cos(e^{-x})}{e^x-e^{-x}}dx$$
Use substitution $t=e^{x}$:
$$I=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos t-\cos \frac{1}{t}}{t-\frac{1}{t}}\dfrac{dt}{t}=\dfrac{1}{4}\operatorname{Re}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{it}-e^{\frac{i}{t}}}{t^2-1}dt=\dfrac{1}{4}\operatorname{Re}J$$
It can be solved using contour integration with path with radiuses $R$ (purple) and $\varepsilon$ (greens): 
Integrand has 3 special points: $z=0$, $z=\pm 1$, but contour includes only $z=0$
Thus consider $\large \oint_C \normalsize \dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{\frac{i}{z}}}{z^2-1}dz=2 \pi i \cdot \operatorname{Res}[z=0]$
The integrand can be rewritten as $\dfrac{e^{iz}}{z^2-1}-\dfrac{e^{\frac{i}{z}}}{z^2-1}$, where the first summand is holomorphic in $z=0$, then residue of it is $0$
Since the point $z=0$ is essentially special for the second summand, we have to multiply the series to extract coefficients at $z^{-1}$:
$$\dfrac{e^{\frac{i}{z}}}{z^2-1}=-\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} z^{2n}\right)\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \dfrac{i^n}{z^n n!}\right)$$
Now we need to choose such numbers n and k that the reduction yields $z^{-1}$:
$$z^{2n}\cdot \dfrac{i^k}{z^k k!}=\dfrac{i^k}{z^{k-2n} k!} \implies k=2n+1$$
$$\dfrac{i^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\dfrac{1}{z^{2n+1-2n}}=i\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\dfrac{1}{z}$$
$$\implies \operatorname{Res}[z=0]=-2\pi i \cdot \left( - i \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\right)=-2\pi \sin 1$$
Next step is contour decomposition into curves:
$$\oint_C = \sum^4_{n=1} \int_{L_n} + \int_{C_R} - \int_{C_{\varepsilon_1}} + \int_{C_{\varepsilon_2}} - \int_{C_{\varepsilon_3}}$$
Using the estimates it is easy to realize that the integrals on the half circles turn to $0$, when $R \to \infty$ and $\varepsilon \to 0$
Than we have:
$-2 \pi \sin 1  = \sum^4_{n=1} L_n = \large\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\normalsize\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{\frac{i}{x}}}{x^{2}-1}dx = J$
Going back to the re-designations made at the very top:
$$I=\dfrac{-2 \pi \sin 1}{4} = -\dfrac{\pi \sin 1}{2}$$
$$\implies \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(e^x)-\cos(e^{-x})}{e^x-e^{-x}}dx = -\dfrac{\pi \sin 1}{2}$$
